# Dictionary in java using hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I am writing a little  phone directory just to practice my knowledge about java.
The problem is in the code below  i want the code to display the name and the number whenever i call the getname method. I am a beginner and i really wish to make this project work.

```
public class Phone {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> name;
    HashMap<String, Integer> namelist = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Integer number;
    String names;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    Phone() {

        // get user to enter name and number
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter name ");
        names = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter number ");
        String nums = scan.nextLine();
        number = Integer.parseInt(nums);

        namelist.put(names, number); // set key and value to namelist object;

        setName(namelist); //

    }

    void printValue() {

        System.out.print(namelist.get(names));

    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param names
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(HashMap<String, Integer> names) {
        this.name = names;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Phone ph = new Phone();
        Gui window = new Gui();
        System.out.println(ph.getName());
        ph.printValue();


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 hashmaps ?

Comment: You have some fundamental problems.  The `Phone()` constructor should only initialize the `Phone` object.  The addition of a name/number pair should occur, probably, in a loop in `main()`. `getName()` should take an argument of the name you are looking for, and it should return the corresponding phone number.

Comment: Your class should be named PhoneDirectory, contains a Set of PhoneEntry class defined as one instance of class Person and an [international phone number](https://www.csoft.co.uk/phone_numbers/index.htm): a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by saying "display the name and the number", you want to display all contacts stored in the phone. So the quesiton seems like how to print all elements in a hashmap.

```
        for(String name : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println("name is " + name);
        System.out.println("contact is " + map.get(name));}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getName()` method should return a String, not a HashMap; you'll need to concatenate the name and number before returning them, e.g. `return name + "; " + Integer.toString(number);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even easier answer:

```
System.out.println(map);
```

This invokes the toString() method on Map which invokes the toString() methods of the key and value and that implementation reports key/value pairings as such:

"joe" -> "123456789"

The only caveat is the default does not place a newline between elements. If you want to do that you can do:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry: map.Entry())
    system.out.println(entry);
```